# Class that returns value by name

Tags: c#

I am totally new to C# and I am having a little issue with understanding how I can make this happen.

I have this class that creates data binding for a UI dropdown node. I haven't written this. I am just trying to tap into it.

```
public override IEnumerable<AssociativeNode> BuildOutputAst(List<AssociativeNode> inputAstNodes)
{
    if (Items.Count == 0 ||
        Items[0].Name == NO_FAMILY_TYPES ||
        SelectedIndex == -1)
    {
        return new[] { AstFactory.BuildAssignment(GetAstIdentifierForOutputIndex(0), AstFactory.BuildNullNode()) };
    }

    var args = new List<AssociativeNode>
    {
        AstFactory.BuildStringNode(((string) Items[SelectedIndex].Name).ToString())
    };

    var func = new Func<string, int>(Data.byName);
    var functionCall = AstFactory.BuildFunctionCall(func, args);

    return new[] { AstFactory.BuildAssignment(GetAstIdentifierForOutputIndex(0), functionCall) };
}
```

The problem is at the end when I am making a new `func` variable. Data.byName should return a piece of data by a key name. For that I have used a dictionary like so:

```
public class Data
{
    public string sProcessName { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, int> dOffsets { get; set; }

    public Data()
    {
        sProcessName = "Client";

        Dictionary<string, int> dOffsets = new Dictionary<string, int>()
        {
            {"Left", 11},
            {"Center", 22},
            {"Right", 33}
        };
    }

    public static int byName(string name)
    {
        if (name == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("name");
        }
        int intValue = new Data().dOffsets[name];
        return intValue;
    }
}
```

This `Data()` class sits in a separate DLL but the idea is that I call `Data.byName("Left")` and get back an `int` 11.

Is this byName definition even required? I am curious if I could just use `Data().dOffsets[name]` and not having to wrap this whole thing like this

Comment: Your code won't work as is, as your constructor creates a *local* `dOffsets`. Remove the `Dictionary<string, int>` at the start of the line in the constructor. As for your question about accessibility, yes, they would be able to just directly use `.dOfffsets`.

Comment: Have you tried it to see?  It seems like the only thing you'd be missing in the null check.

Comment: @DStanley that was it! Thank you. It works. I am still not very happy with this ```byName``` wrapper instead of Dictionary access methods but I guess it has to be a function so I don't have much choice here.